# How to compute $P+P$ on an elliptic curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, cryptography

Let $E(\mathbb{F}_{11})$ the elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_{11}$ given by the equation $y^2=x^3+2x+2$ and $P=(1,4)$. I have to compute $P+P$.

My idea: Let $f(x,y)=x^3+2x+2-y^2$

The tangent line to $E(\mathbb{F}_{11})$ in $P$ has equation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(P)\cdot (x-1)+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(P)\cdot (y-4)=0\Rightarrow 5\cdot(x-1)+3\cdot(y-4)=0\Rightarrow y=2\cdot(x-1)+4\Rightarrow y=2\cdot x+2 $

Now intersect the tangent line with the curve and obtain the equation: $4\cdot x^2+8\cdot x+4=x^3+2\cdot x+2\Rightarrow x^3+7\cdot x^2 +5\cdot x+9=0$.

By Viete 's relations: $x_1+x_2+x_3=4\Rightarrow 1+1+x_3=4\Rightarrow x_3=2\Rightarrow y_3=6\Rightarrow $ The points of coordinates (2,6)$\Rightarrow  P+P=(2,5).$

Comment: You've got the wrong tangent due to a sign error. $5(x-1)+3(y-4)=0$ implies that
$$y=4-\frac53(x-1)=4+\frac63(x-1)=2x+2.$$
Alternatively, implicit differentiation tell us that
$$2y y'=(3x^2+2)\implies y'=\frac{3x^2+2}{2y}.$$ Therefore $y'(P)=5/8=16/8=2$.

Comment: @Problemsolving: You got a nice comment, but why are you trying to use this method as opposed to the point doubling or point addition formulas?

Comment: @Moo, for my own part, I think that a lot is to be gained by doing at least a few computations from first principles.

Comment: @Moo There exists too many calculators that makes this computation in a short time. My goal it's to understand how can I do it myself.